# Finding the appropriate polynomial fit for set of data

Tags: polynomials, regression, regression-analysis, python

Is there a function or library in Python to automatically compute the best polynomial fit for a set of data points? I am not really interested in the ML use case of generalizing to a set of new data, I am just focusing on the data I have. I realize the higher the degree, the better the fit. However, I want something that penalizes or looks at where the error elbows? When I say elbowing, I mean something like this (although usually it is not so drastic or obvious): [image]

One idea I had was to use Numpy's polyfit: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html to compute polynomial regression for a range of orders/degrees. Polyfit requires the user to specify the degree of polynomial, which poses a challenge because I don't have any assumptions or preconceived notions. The higher the degree of fit, the lower the error will be but eventually it plateaus like the image above. Therefore if I want to automatically compute the degree of polynomial where the error curve elbows: if my error is E and d is my degree, I want to maximize (E[d+1]-E[d]) - (E[d] - E[d-1]).

Is this even a valid approach? Are there other tools and approaches, perhaps using well-established Python libraries like Numpy or Scipy, that can help with finding the appropriate polynomial fit (without me having to specify the order/degree)? I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: *maximize (E[d+1]-E[d]) - (E[d+1] - E[d])* ? Typo, I suppose

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.  I meant (E[d+1]-E[d]) - (E[d] - E[d-1])

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called model selection. You may find a popular library method for this, but it's important you know how the model is selected, even if it means writing a little code yourself. The basic idea is to take a measure of fit quality, then penalise by a measure of model complexity. There are [many popular criteria for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Methods_for_choosing_the_set_of_candidate_models), so think about which is appropriate for your purposes